# XNA libraries are not getting registered. Unable to compile or debug project

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, assemblies

I am facing this problem with only Windows Phone solutions. My old solution for a pc game, works fine. Can anyone help me what is the issue?

Till now, I have tried to reinstall windows phone tools. Source code is downloaded from MSDN's official XNA tutorial page. I checked GAC too, and libraries for PC version are already there. But, libraries for XBox and Phone version are not there at all (like XNA.Framework.Avatar, XNA.Framework.Touch). I am unable to figure out, why this is happening, considering I used MS's default installer for phone tools. All the dlls exist in ProgramFiles/XNA/v4.0 folder, but somehow they are not registered to GAC.

Ok, reinstalled XNA 4.0 and phone tools, same issue. It is just not registering the assemblies at all. What to do?

Comment: I think the best option would be contact Microsoft.

Comment: New update. I am not even getting the option to debug the software anymore. Same issue is happening for PC version too. Files for PC version are there, and no warning is issued. But, I am unable to select debug option. clearly some setting is wrong somewhere.

Comment: one more update. for pc version, old projects that I have already created, work fine. The ones that I downloaded from MSDN site does not work.

Comment: uninstalling everything .net, and reinstalling from fresh. hopefully, that will help.

Comment: The reference assemblies for compiling your app for the XBox and Phone are not located in the GAC. They are located in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References' by default. This is because they are for reference only during compilation. If after reinstalling you still cannot compile than something is definitely askew. However, successfully compiling does not mean you will be able to debug.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Technically, the code that MSDN site provided is supposed to work as is, but it is referencing those other libraries. Sadly, those libraries are required for phone games to work. Also, I am not able to debug any phone project. Just an option to build or rebuild is available. I tried to package the project and install the application for testing, but it didn't get installed. gave me same errors at that time too, saying files are missing.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the Phone Projects? Right-Click the project file and you should see a 'Upgrade Project' selection. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Final update. I tried reinstalling everything, including Visual studio. For the old projects, I do not get any error, and I am able to debug them successfully. 
For new projects, the debug option is disabled, so I am unable to create any new project. For past two days, I am just creating copies of old project and editing it. I checked all project specific and visual studio's settings, but couldn't find anything. 
And lastly, if I select Windows Phone game instead of Windows Game, I get the warnings that assemblies couldn't be found. Same exist in XNA folder, but are not registered in GAC.

Comment: I have till now downloaded 2gb worth of updates, because of this reinstallation, and still no luck. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with the installation?

Comment: One more update. I tried to download existing project from other sources than MSDN, and those works fine. So, now, only new or downloaded from MSDN project doesn't work. Phone projects does not give that warning anymore after I reinstalled Zune today. Turns out, libraries required are registered by Zune, and not by phone tools, which honestly is very idiotic design choice.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using ?

Comment: VS 2010 ultimate edition. anyways, I am trying to go with alternate methods like editing old projects for now. it is painful, but atleast it is useable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before.
Try installing the "Games for Windows" component

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5549

Then install XNA again.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about this. Moved to Windows 8 development now. Although, I tried to run that code again, after reinstalling GFWL, and it worked fine.